# Runtime error Javascript is undefined

Tags: javascript, html

As some background I've come via VB6 then VB.Net and am now trying out Bootstrap/MVC with C# so excuse the queries... I've SO searched and been on YouTube as well but a struggling a little. I've my approach is wrong do tell me!

**Aim:**
Stored procedure to run and, in this case, confirm if the username and password are correct. I'll be wanting to add in insert/edit to later Stored Procedures.

**Issue:** 
When I run the code on the website I get no error or result. In debug mode I get:

```
Unhandled exception at line 133, column 5 in http://localhost:49647/Account/Login

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined
```

**Thoughts**
I am not a JS programmer but would assume I'd need to add something to 'Dim' the value in some way? Looking at [0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948763/0x800a1391-javascript-runtime-error-jquery-is-undefined) I might need to call something?

**User.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration; 

namespace Login.BL
{
    public class User
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        //[Required]
        public int Username { get; set; }
        //[Required]
        public int UserPassword { get; set; }

    }
    public class UserBusinessLogic
    {
        string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myTaylorWoodrowSQL"].ConnectionString;
        public int CheckUserLogin(User User)
        {
            //Check the user is valid!!!!
            using (SqlConnection conObj = new SqlConnection(conStr))
            {
                SqlCommand comObj = new SqlCommand("retrieveUserByNameAndPassword", conObj);
                comObj.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                comObj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Username", User.Username));
                comObj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", User.UserPassword));
                conObj.Open();
                return Convert.ToInt32(comObj.ExecuteScalar());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Extract from **Login.cshtml** I can post full code

```
<script> 
    $("#Login").click(function ()
    {
        var dataObject = { UserName: $("#UserName").val(), Password: $("#Password").val() };
        $.ajax({
            url:'@Url.Action("Login","User")',
            type:"POST",
            data: dataObject,
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(result)
            {
                if(result.toString()=="Success")
                {
                    alert(result);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert(result);
                }
            },
            error: function (result)
            {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: are you including jquery before your script?

Comment: Did you add a `<script>` tag for jquery, something like `<script src='/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Means jquery is not loaded into your page. So if its a Default MVC application it would be loaded in the `_Layout page`. But I think you have written the login page without using the default layout, So you can add this line of code to your login page head section (if you are using a layout page then head section of this layout) and everything must be fine.

```
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

The default MVC application will have the Jquery and validation related files bundled under this name `~/bundles/jquery`and this is how we use it, Else if its a empty application then you must create a new bundle, Or add only the reference of the jquery file to the page like this.

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>  
//note just drag and drop the file into the page and VS will do the work for you of putting the proper URL there.
```

Comment: Thanks. I had used the default MVC layout (or think I did!) but added both of the above and it appears to be working! Thanks

Comment: Is there  a better and cleaner example out there I should use @Reddy ?

Comment: Don't add both, Jquery should be loaded only once. Else it might cause issues while using some plugin's or might effect your custom code etc.

Comment: @indofraiser If you are looking for a start in MVC then I think this is a good reference for you.. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/866143/Learn-MVC-Project-in-days-Day

Answer (score 1):

You appear not to have loaded the jquery library before running your script.

See https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ for details on how to include it.

It's best if you get a local copy of jquery.js and then insert a line such as

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

before the script tag with your own code.