# Querying SQL from MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

**Aim:** I want to be able to press a submit button, such as:

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" />
```

and run the below code and return some sort of result i.e. let the user in, or not.

**Notes:**
Earlier I posted and resolved: [Runtime error Javascript is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746890/runtime-error-javascript-is-undefined) if that's any guide as I build up. (On the plus side Menus etc.. all working!)

**User.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Login.BL
{
    public class User
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Username { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int UserPassword { get; set; }

    }

    public class UserBusinessLogic
    {
        string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mySQL"].ConnectionString;
        public int CheckUserLogin(User User)
        {
            //Check the user is valid!!!!
            using (SqlConnection conObj = new SqlConnection(conStr))
            {
                SqlCommand comObj = new SqlCommand("retrieveUserByNameAndPassword", conObj);
                comObj.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                comObj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Username", User.Username));
                comObj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserPassword", User.UserPassword));
                conObj.Open();
                return Convert.ToInt32(comObj.ExecuteScalar());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Login.cshml**

```
@using Orientation.Models
@model LoginViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>  

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Register as a new user", "Register")
                </p>
                @* Enable this once you have account confirmation enabled for password reset functionality
                    <p>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ForgotPassword")
                    </p>*@
            }
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section id="socialLoginForm">
            @Html.Partial("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", new ExternalLoginListViewModel { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
}

<script>
    //$document.ready(function () {
    //    $("myModal").modal({
    //        backdrop: 'static',
    //    });
    //});

    $("login").click(function ()
    {
        var dataObject = {Username: $("#Username").val, Password:$("#Password").val};
        $.ajax({
            url:'url.action("Login","User)',
            type: "POST",
            data: dataObject,
            datatype:"json",
            success: function(result)
            {
                if(result.tostring()=="Success")
                {
                    alert(result);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert(result); 
                }
            },
            error: function(result)
            {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your jQuery selector is wrong. There is no such element called `login` in your page. Give an `id` to your submit button so that you can use it as your jQuery selector.

```
<input type="submit" id="loginBtn" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" />
```

Now in your javscript, listen to the click on this button(Use the Id selector). Since your form elements are already in a form, you may simply serialize the form and send it.

```
$(function(){

  $("#loginBtn").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var _form=$(this).closest("form");

    $.post(_form.attr("action"),_form.serialize(),function(response){

       if(reponse.Status==="Success")
       {
         alert("Valid user");
       }
       else
       {
         alert(response.Message);
       }
    });

  });

});
```

Now in your Login action method, call your custom method and use the return value of that to return a JSON object back to the client

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(User user)
{       
   try
   {
     var bl=new UserBusinessLogic();
     var result = bl.CheckUserLogin(user);
     //based on the result return something
     if(result==1) //demo purpose. Change to match with what your code actually returns
     {
        return Json(new {Status="Success" });
     }
     return Json(new {Status==="Invalid", Message="Invalid user credentials" });
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
      return Json(new {Status==="Valid", Message="Code crashed!.
                   Put a breakpoint in your action method and see what is happening" });
  }
}
```

Comment: Oops. Well that will not help. I'll amend that tomorrow.

Comment: What do you mean, that will not help.

Comment: I meant I didn't help myself,  apologies. I'll take a look in a few hours when I get up.